# why feature selection technique doesn't work properly?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, feature-selection

I am using Pyspark to train a machine-learning model for network traffic classification. I tried using the Univariate Feature Selector with a Selection Threshold of 42 to select a subset of features from the dataset, which consists of 50 features, and has 6 nominal features that were removed. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import UnivariateFeatureSelector
selector = UnivariateFeatureSelector(featuresCol='features', outputCol="selectedFeatures", labelCol="label")
selector.setFeatureType("continuous").setLabelType("categorical").setSelectionThreshold(42)                   
result_2 = selector.fit(result_1).transform(result_1)
```

The number 42 represents the number of selected features, which is a value I changed every time I ran this code. Surprisingly, the accuracy drops significantly to only 0.82 when this stage is added. When I removed this feature selection stage and continued without any feature selection, the accuracy improved to 0.97. Why is this happening?

Note that I also tried using the Variance Threshold Selector with a threshold set to 0, but no features were removed. Here is a snapshot of my code for this:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VarianceThresholdSelector
selector = VarianceThresholdSelector(varianceThreshold=0.0, featuresCol='features',outputCol="selected_Features")
```